# How to resize cell label as per my text length in iphone UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have surfed but not working any of the solution as per my requirement

Let me explain first ! I want to resize my label as per my text string ! I have referred some of stackoverflow questions !

Now look I have first string as **"Hello First,"** This string completely fits with cell.

Now the problem with second string. Second string is **"Hello Second, How are you ? Everythings all right ? Hows all there ?"** This is too long string as per cell content. So I want to make my cell resizable as per string text !!

How can I ?

Answer (score 2):

```
     CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(3000,3000);
     UIFont *dateFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
     CGSize dateStringSize = ["YOURString" sizeWithFont:dateFont 
                               constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                   lineBreakMode:"Yourlable".lineBreakMode];
```

It will give "**Width and height**" .As per height you will fix your "**heightForRowAtIndexpath**" in table view cell(through dynamic)

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    return dateStringSize.height;
  } 
                       (or)else
       "set your lable height according to string height"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement this delegate method **`heightForRowAtIndexPath`**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //Load text in NSString which you want in Cell's LabelText.
   NSString *cellText=[valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   //define font for Labeltext...
   UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];

   CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(330.0f, MAXFLOAT);

  //sizeWithFont: Returns the size of the string if it were rendered with the specified constraints. So it will break your line according to font size and constraint size.

   CGSize labelSize_val = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

   return  labelSize_val.height+20;  // Add 20 in height so your UITableView will be neat and clean.

}
```

> Note:

`– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated in iOS 7. Use boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making dynamic size of your label, you can set it maximum (as in your thought) then set numberOfLines property of label. That will allow and move to next line when it reaches end of label. One more thing to set proper size of your cells. Only you've know the exact length of your data.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In above function you should calculate the height of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Here you should set proper frame and numberOfLines to zero to textLabel to accomodate the long string.